# Covariance Matrix Estimation for the Generalized Method of Moments

Tags: r, econometrics, covariance-matrix, generalized-moments, macroeconomics

I am solving and empirical exercise on the Generalized Method of Moments. It's a classical application/test of a famous model in Economics. There are 2 parameters $(\beta, \gamma)$ to be estimated with 5 moment conditions. The theoretical moment conditions are:

$E\left(\left[\beta \left(\frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t}\right)^{-\gamma}R_{t+1} - 1\right]\otimes z_{t}\right) = 0, \qquad g(data_t; \beta, \gamma)\equiv   \beta \left[\left(\frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t}\right)^{-\gamma}R_{t+1} - 1\right]\otimes z_{t}$

where $c_{t}$ denotes the household consumption, $R_t$ is the return on the SP500 index and $z_t = (1, R_{t}, R_{t-1}, \frac{c_{t}}{c_{t-1}}, \frac{c_{t-1}}{c_{t-2}})$ is a vector of instruments. The goal is estimating the parameters using a two-stage GMM procedure: get a first estimate using and identity matrix, then use this estimate to compute the efficient weighting matrix that will lead to the final estimate. I will leave the data I am using posted below using `dput`. I am using R on my computation. We are not supposed to use packages, we must implement the optimization on our own.

I get sensible estimates but the final covariance matrix for the estimators isn't invertible, which smells very fishy. The code is below:

```
moments <- function(params){
  beta <- params[1]; g <- params[2];
  m1 <- beta * gmm.data$c_ratio^(-g) * gmm.data$R - 1
  m2 <- m1 * gmm.data$R_lag1
  m3 <- m1 * gmm.data$R_lag2
  m4 <- m1 * gmm.data$c_ratio_lag1
  m5 <- m1 * gmm.data$c_ratio_lag2
  return(do.call(cbind, list(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)))}

# Using the identity matrix for estimation
gmm.fn <- function(x){colMeans(moments(x)) %*% colMeans(moments(x))}
first.pass <- optim(par = c(0.8, 2), gmm.fn, lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(0.9999, 200))

m <- moments(first.pass$par)

# Computing the HC-only covariance matrix for moments
S.hat <- 1/nrow(gmm.data) * t(m) %*% m
W.hc <- solve(S.hat)
gmm.fn.hc <- function(x) {colMeans(moments(x)) %*% W.hc %*% colMeans(moments(x))}
second.pass.hc <- optim(par = first.pass$par, gmm.fn.hc, lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(1, 200))
```

The code above will give the estimates for the parameters. They are around what would be expected. To compute the covariance matrix, we need to approximate the Jacobian matrix. Let $\theta = (\beta, \gamma)'$. Then, we must compute

$G = E\left(\frac{\partial g(data_t; \theta)}{\partial \theta'}\right)$

It turns out that the Kroencker structure helps a bit since
$$
\frac{\partial g(data_t; \theta)}{\partial \theta'} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[\left(\frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t}\right)^{-\gamma}R_{t+1}\right]\otimes z_{t}\\
-\beta\left[\left(\frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t}\right)^{-\gamma}R_{t+1}\cdot \log(c_{t+1}/c_t)\right]\otimes z_{t}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I implemented the following function to use the common approximation:

```
# Compute the empirical G matrix
Grad <- function(params){
  beta <- params[1]; g <- params[2];
  
  # Derivatives with respect to beta
  db1 <- mean(gmm.data$c_ratio^(-g) * gmm.data$R)
  db2 <- mean(db1 * gmm.data$R_lag1)
  db3 <- mean(db1 * gmm.data$R_lag2)
  db4 <- mean(db1 * gmm.data$c_ratio_lag1)
  db5 <- mean(db1 * gmm.data$c_ratio_lag2)
  db <- c(db1, db2, db3, db4, db5)
  
  # Derivatives with respect to gamma
  dg1 <- mean(-beta * gmm.data$c_ratio^(-g) * gmm.data$R * log(gmm.data$c_ratio))
  dg2 <- mean(dg1 * gmm.data$R_lag1)
  dg3 <- mean(dg1 * gmm.data$R_lag2)
  dg4 <- mean(dg1 * gmm.data$c_ratio_lag1)
  dg5 <- mean(dg1 * gmm.data$c_ratio_lag2)
  dg <- c(dg1, dg2, dg3, dg4, dg5)
  return(rbind(db, dg))
}
```

The final covariance matrix is $(G'S^{-1}G)^{-1}$. Just notice that, technically, the `Grad` function is really computing $G'$. Now, my problem:

```
HC.cov.mat <- solve(Grad(second.pass.hc$par) %*% solve(S.hat) %*% t(Grad(second.pass.hc$par)))
```

`R` is complaining that `HC.cov.mat` cannot be computed because it cannot invert $(G'S^{-1}G)$. I can't understand what is wrong either with the code of the derivations. Any ideas?

---

The dataset:

```
> dput(head(gmm.data, 150))
structure(list(pcecc96 = c(1976.01403808594, 1994.91796875, 2020.08203125, 
2012.00805664062, 2014.61401367188, 2013.86499023438, 2043.8349609375, 
2053.77392578125, 2095.083984375, 2117.27709960938, 2143.30590820312, 
2160.580078125, 2191.14990234375, 2206.4990234375, 2227.32006835938, 
2257.53588867188, 2276.34692382812, 2321.02392578125, 2362.0810546875, 
2405.712890625, 2412.580078125, 2466.38208007812, 2493.583984375, 
2536.42993164062, 2607.73608398438, 2646.23291015625, 2653.01391601562, 
2683.30908203125, 2694.48803710938, 2710.01391601562, 2747.06396484375, 
2761.12890625, 2778.02587890625, 2844.60107421875, 2887.9169921875, 
2942.0419921875, 2955.31298828125, 2988.08203125, 3007.35791015625, 
3022.02001953125, 3046.17309570312, 3065.07397460938, 3078.958984375, 
3105.95190429688, 3097.52001953125, 3156.97802734375, 3185.99291992188, 
3211.39404296875, 3264.67895507812, 3307.76708984375, 3370.73608398438, 
3422.68188476562, 3503.0009765625, 3566.95703125, 3565.34912109375, 
3577.89794921875, 3567.22705078125, 3535.31201171875, 3548.041015625, 
3563.28198242188, 3511.19702148438, 3540.64697265625, 3598.88598632812, 
3650.03491210938, 3689.28491210938, 3763.04809570312, 3797.669921875, 
3837.65405273438, 3887.44702148438, 3933.26806640625, 3954.59594726562, 
3991.98901367188, 4052.01000976562, 4074.77392578125, 4161.88720703125, 
4179.36279296875, 4213.087890625, 4234.9091796875, 4232.1591796875, 
4273.341796875, 4283.97509765625, 4277.85107421875, 4181.509765625, 
4227.37890625, 4284.494140625, 4298.84716796875, 4299.16015625, 
4319.046875, 4289.50390625, 4321.10009765625, 4334.26220703125, 
4363.31787109375, 4439.7490234375, 4483.64501953125, 4574.94384765625, 
4656.98193359375, 4731.19384765625, 4770.45703125, 4837.2900390625, 
4873.1650390625, 4936.29296875, 5020.1630859375, 5066.25, 5162.47509765625, 
5173.64306640625, 5218.85107421875, 5275.72021484375, 5369.048828125, 
5401.97998046875, 5407.3720703125, 5481.166015625, 5543.72314453125, 
5555.451171875, 5653.587890625, 5695.326171875, 5745.93310546875, 
5811.26416015625, 5838.22509765625, 5865.47705078125, 5922.26123046875, 
5948, 5998.05810546875, 6016.3291015625, 6040.1630859375, 5994.2119140625, 
5971.671875, 6021.1630859375, 6051.18408203125, 6048.15576171875, 
6161.39794921875, 6203.22412109375, 6269.7177734375, 6344.44580078125, 
6368.77197265625, 6426.703125, 6498.22900390625, 6555.27392578125, 
6630.2529296875, 6681.8408203125, 6732.791015625, 6805.5810546875, 
6822.51904296875, 6882.330078125, 6944.7001953125, 6993.14404296875, 
7057.64111328125, 7133.56591796875, 7176.75390625, 7233.91796875, 
7310.169921875), sp500 = c(57.7633018493652, 56.2766990661621, 
56.0699996948242, 55.7200012207031, 55.3333015441895, 62.0032997131348, 
65.9832992553711, 66.8300018310547, 70.2733001708984, 69.8600006103516, 
62.2233009338379, 57.8300018310547, 59.61669921875, 65.5500030517578, 
69.6699981689453, 70.9666976928711, 73.2733001708984, 77.5466995239258, 
80.3000030517578, 82.8767013549805, 84.75, 86.5667037963867, 
87.4300003051758, 86.9266967773438, 91.7566986083984, 91.629997253418, 
88.1466979980469, 81.4332962036133, 79.8167037963867, 87.0766983032227, 
91.6600036621094, 94.4366989135742, 94.5400009155273, 91.6267013549805, 
98.013298034668, 99.9032974243164, 105.233299255371, 100.933296203613, 
101.680000305176, 94.4666976928711, 94.2799987792969, 88.7067031860352, 
79.1999969482422, 78.7399978637695, 86.2332992553711, 96.7332992553711, 
101.440002441406, 98.5466995239258, 96.4132995605469, 105.400001525879, 
108.166702270508, 109.199996948242, 114.066703796387, 115, 107.433296203613, 
105.066703796387, 102.193298339844, 95.6667022705078, 90.6399993896484, 
74.486701965332, 69.4167022705078, 78.8133010864258, 89.0733032226562, 
87.6232986450195, 89.1132965087891, 99.5199966430664, 101.63330078125, 
104.333297729492, 102.599998474121, 101.800003051758, 99.0333023071289, 
98.0599975585938, 93.9467010498047, 89.3499984741211, 95.9266967773438, 
101.663299560547, 97.1399993896484, 99.3467025756836, 101.176696777344, 
106.233299255371, 105.333297729492, 110.300003051758, 108.433296203613, 
123.266700744629, 133.13330078125, 131.533294677734, 132.800003051758, 
125.666702270508, 122.166702270508, 114.199996948242, 114.13330078125, 
113.833297729492, 136.733306884766, 147.666702270508, 162.733306884766, 
165.533294677734, 165.766693115234, 160.36669921875, 155.766693115234, 
160.533294677734, 165.199996948242, 177.300003051758, 184.800003051758, 
188.300003051758, 197, 219.966705322266, 240.600006103516, 241.166702270508, 
243.699996948242, 279.299987792969, 293.266693115234, 319.399993896484, 
255.399993896484, 258.100006103516, 263.13330078125, 266.933288574219, 
274.966705322266, 290.700012207031, 313.299987792969, 341.933288574219, 
345.399993896484, 336.293304443359, 349.606689453125, 335.396697998047, 
317.053314208984, 353.343292236328, 378.653289794922, 385.609985351562, 
387.103302001953, 412, 410.163299560547, 417.153289794922, 423.660003662109, 
442.363311767578, 445.463287353516, 453.553314208984, 464.246704101562, 
469.459991455078, 450.986694335938, 460.86669921875, 460.003295898438, 
480.106689453125, 523.690002441406, 565.083312988281, 597.673278808594, 
637.010009765625, 658.966674804688, 660.543273925781, 726.793273925781, 
785.590026855469), R = c(0.98353996764165, 0.974263888392671, 
0.996327087857536, 0.993757829926412, 0.993059948527604, 1.12054220483516, 
1.06419012472966, 1.01283207395263, 1.05152324174026, 0.994118682920231, 
0.890685662613892, 0.929394631322202, 1.03089568271007, 1.09952419222736, 
1.06285270671817, 1.01861202178851, 1.03250260408072, 1.05832137140077, 
1.03550510266375, 1.0320883960809, 1.02260344118905, 1.02143603299571, 
1.00997261615528, 0.994243354385506, 1.05556407881719, 0.99861915961557, 
0.961985164686435, 0.923838306517366, 0.980148262656782, 1.0909583353048, 
1.05263526808201, 1.03029342287287, 1.00109387561342, 0.969184477127836, 
1.06970235297399, 1.01928309145337, 1.05335161069225, 0.959138380320825, 
1.00739799580166, 0.929058786480575, 0.998023653645847, 0.940885705712529, 
0.892829900150211, 0.99419193052781, 1.09516512058542, 1.12176270756967, 
1.04865649390919, 0.971477692745998, 0.978351380881498, 1.09321018994572, 
1.02624953230147, 1.00955279819061, 1.04456691377429, 1.00818202133095, 
0.934202575683594, 0.977971518227075, 0.972651607476794, 0.936134793813663, 
0.947456087002499, 0.821786214330434, 0.931934163266029, 1.135365099588, 
1.13018109880944, 0.983721221452716, 1.0170045853878, 1.11678055399119, 
1.02123496995044, 1.02656606572341, 0.983386902426251, 0.992202773545215, 
0.972822193893037, 0.990171944933062, 0.958053267273118, 0.951071165625638, 
1.07360602591535, 1.05980194227388, 0.955507049343755, 1.02271673049105, 
1.01842028123949, 1.04997793601777, 0.991528065755395, 1.04715228165571, 
0.983076094320065, 1.1367975064888, 1.08004270396643, 0.987981924175796, 
1.00963032498446, 0.946285386917726, 0.972148549004923, 0.934788242833752, 
0.999415970501099, 0.997371467838884, 1.2011714464224, 1.07996146392449, 
1.10203115788865, 1.01720599087285, 1.00140997880792, 0.967424132103965, 
0.971315702537215, 1.03060090361534, 1.02906999622649, 1.07324459035739, 
1.04230118370506, 1.01893939362663, 1.04620285080851, 1.11658226051911, 
1.09380192675533, 1.00235534560522, 1.01050433021592, 1.14608121169689, 
1.05000610788647, 1.08911104259283, 0.799624291725121, 1.01057170035848, 
1.01950133498143, 1.01444130325461, 1.03009522263393, 1.0572189526231, 
1.07774329080469, 1.09139260101143, 1.01013854292082, 0.973634367069925, 
1.03958861158952, 0.95935434909067, 0.945308394809631, 1.11446017562656, 
1.07163004962796, 1.01837220418819, 1.00387260887196, 1.06431538524546, 
0.995541989224628, 1.01704196899592, 1.01559789656792, 1.0441469762163, 
1.00700775924104, 1.01816092837534, 1.02357691931152, 1.01122956244483, 
0.960649901045064, 1.02190753076953, 0.998126566050929, 1.0437027163369, 
1.0907783914403, 1.07904162835628, 1.05767285119069, 1.06581644579367, 
1.03446832028141, 1.00239253240167, 1.10029622980832, 1.08089886772355
), R_lag1 = c(1.02127232067638, 0.98353996764165, 0.974263888392671, 
0.996327087857536, 0.993757829926412, 0.993059948527604, 1.12054220483516, 
1.06419012472966, 1.01283207395263, 1.05152324174026, 0.994118682920231, 
0.890685662613892, 0.929394631322202, 1.03089568271007, 1.09952419222736, 
1.06285270671817, 1.01861202178851, 1.03250260408072, 1.05832137140077, 
1.03550510266375, 1.0320883960809, 1.02260344118905, 1.02143603299571, 
1.00997261615528, 0.994243354385506, 1.05556407881719, 0.99861915961557, 
0.961985164686435, 0.923838306517366, 0.980148262656782, 1.0909583353048, 
1.05263526808201, 1.03029342287287, 1.00109387561342, 0.969184477127836, 
1.06970235297399, 1.01928309145337, 1.05335161069225, 0.959138380320825, 
1.00739799580166, 0.929058786480575, 0.998023653645847, 0.940885705712529, 
0.892829900150211, 0.99419193052781, 1.09516512058542, 1.12176270756967, 
1.04865649390919, 0.971477692745998, 0.978351380881498, 1.09321018994572, 
1.02624953230147, 1.00955279819061, 1.04456691377429, 1.00818202133095, 
0.934202575683594, 0.977971518227075, 0.972651607476794, 0.936134793813663, 
0.947456087002499, 0.821786214330434, 0.931934163266029, 1.135365099588, 
1.13018109880944, 0.983721221452716, 1.0170045853878, 1.11678055399119, 
1.02123496995044, 1.02656606572341, 0.983386902426251, 0.992202773545215, 
0.972822193893037, 0.990171944933062, 0.958053267273118, 0.951071165625638, 
1.07360602591535, 1.05980194227388, 0.955507049343755, 1.02271673049105, 
1.01842028123949, 1.04997793601777, 0.991528065755395, 1.04715228165571, 
0.983076094320065, 1.1367975064888, 1.08004270396643, 0.987981924175796, 
1.00963032498446, 0.946285386917726, 0.972148549004923, 0.934788242833752, 
0.999415970501099, 0.997371467838884, 1.2011714464224, 1.07996146392449, 
1.10203115788865, 1.01720599087285, 1.00140997880792, 0.967424132103965, 
0.971315702537215, 1.03060090361534, 1.02906999622649, 1.07324459035739, 
1.04230118370506, 1.01893939362663, 1.04620285080851, 1.11658226051911, 
1.09380192675533, 1.00235534560522, 1.01050433021592, 1.14608121169689, 
1.05000610788647, 1.08911104259283, 0.799624291725121, 1.01057170035848, 
1.01950133498143, 1.01444130325461, 1.03009522263393, 1.0572189526231, 
1.07774329080469, 1.09139260101143, 1.01013854292082, 0.973634367069925, 
1.03958861158952, 0.95935434909067, 0.945308394809631, 1.11446017562656, 
1.07163004962796, 1.01837220418819, 1.00387260887196, 1.06431538524546, 
0.995541989224628, 1.01704196899592, 1.01559789656792, 1.0441469762163, 
1.00700775924104, 1.01816092837534, 1.02357691931152, 1.01122956244483, 
0.960649901045064, 1.02190753076953, 0.998126566050929, 1.0437027163369, 
1.0907783914403, 1.07904162835628, 1.05767285119069, 1.06581644579367, 
1.03446832028141, 1.00239253240167, 1.10029622980832), R_lag2 = c(1.03584503108215, 
1.02127232067638, 0.98353996764165, 0.974263888392671, 0.996327087857536, 
0.993757829926412, 0.993059948527604, 1.12054220483516, 1.06419012472966, 
1.01283207395263, 1.05152324174026, 0.994118682920231, 0.890685662613892, 
0.929394631322202, 1.03089568271007, 1.09952419222736, 1.06285270671817, 
1.01861202178851, 1.03250260408072, 1.05832137140077, 1.03550510266375, 
1.0320883960809, 1.02260344118905, 1.02143603299571, 1.00997261615528, 
0.994243354385506, 1.05556407881719, 0.99861915961557, 0.961985164686435, 
0.923838306517366, 0.980148262656782, 1.0909583353048, 1.05263526808201, 
1.03029342287287, 1.00109387561342, 0.969184477127836, 1.06970235297399, 
1.01928309145337, 1.05335161069225, 0.959138380320825, 1.00739799580166, 
0.929058786480575, 0.998023653645847, 0.940885705712529, 0.892829900150211, 
0.99419193052781, 1.09516512058542, 1.12176270756967, 1.04865649390919, 
0.971477692745998, 0.978351380881498, 1.09321018994572, 1.02624953230147, 
1.00955279819061, 1.04456691377429, 1.00818202133095, 0.934202575683594, 
0.977971518227075, 0.972651607476794, 0.936134793813663, 0.947456087002499, 
0.821786214330434, 0.931934163266029, 1.135365099588, 1.13018109880944, 
0.983721221452716, 1.0170045853878, 1.11678055399119, 1.02123496995044, 
1.02656606572341, 0.983386902426251, 0.992202773545215, 0.972822193893037, 
0.990171944933062, 0.958053267273118, 0.951071165625638, 1.07360602591535, 
1.05980194227388, 0.955507049343755, 1.02271673049105, 1.01842028123949, 
1.04997793601777, 0.991528065755395, 1.04715228165571, 0.983076094320065, 
1.1367975064888, 1.08004270396643, 0.987981924175796, 1.00963032498446, 
0.946285386917726, 0.972148549004923, 0.934788242833752, 0.999415970501099, 
0.997371467838884, 1.2011714464224, 1.07996146392449, 1.10203115788865, 
1.01720599087285, 1.00140997880792, 0.967424132103965, 0.971315702537215, 
1.03060090361534, 1.02906999622649, 1.07324459035739, 1.04230118370506, 
1.01893939362663, 1.04620285080851, 1.11658226051911, 1.09380192675533, 
1.00235534560522, 1.01050433021592, 1.14608121169689, 1.05000610788647, 
1.08911104259283, 0.799624291725121, 1.01057170035848, 1.01950133498143, 
1.01444130325461, 1.03009522263393, 1.0572189526231, 1.07774329080469, 
1.09139260101143, 1.01013854292082, 0.973634367069925, 1.03958861158952, 
0.95935434909067, 0.945308394809631, 1.11446017562656, 1.07163004962796, 
1.01837220418819, 1.00387260887196, 1.06431538524546, 0.995541989224628, 
1.01704196899592, 1.01559789656792, 1.0441469762163, 1.00700775924104, 
1.01816092837534, 1.02357691931152, 1.01122956244483, 0.960649901045064, 
1.02190753076953, 0.998126566050929, 1.0437027163369, 1.0907783914403, 
1.07904162835628, 1.05767285119069, 1.06581644579367, 1.03446832028141, 
1.00239253240167), c_ratio = c(1.00112627043255, 1.00956669856575, 
1.01261408383412, 0.996003145177041, 1.00129520208562, 0.99962820498993, 
1.01488181722631, 1.00486289990812, 1.02011421903608, 1.01059294777674, 
1.01229352955197, 1.00805959142639, 1.01414889664505, 1.00700505295294, 
1.00943623572941, 1.01356599832316, 1.00833255198761, 1.01962662258791, 
1.01768923122687, 1.01847177760937, 1.0028545332765, 1.02230060773566, 
1.01102907149569, 1.01718247612036, 1.0281128019561, 1.01476254687286, 
1.00256251285869, 1.01141915081287, 1.0041661078677, 1.00576208863889, 
1.01367153452946, 1.00511999050122, 1.00611958848354, 1.02396492985109, 
1.01522741391098, 1.01874188217543, 1.00451081124232, 1.01108818020247, 
1.00645092025743, 1.00487541217674, 1.00799236140587, 1.00620479477444, 
1.00453007329697, 1.00876689818177, 0.997285249409703, 1.01919535868617, 
1.00919071730206, 1.00797274937055, 1.01659245530023, 1.01319827626499, 
1.01903670737095, 1.01541081813793, 1.02346671250822, 1.01825750409875, 
0.999549220766563, 1.00351966320795, 0.99701755092265, 0.991053263891484, 
1.00360053196551, 1.00429560051018, 0.985382868604157, 1.00838743909603, 
1.01644869260382, 1.01421243295163, 1.01075332180243, 1.01999389728661, 
1.00920047400176, 1.01052859560781, 1.01297484558686, 1.01178692459824, 
1.00542243256734, 1.00945559721015, 1.01503536104137, 1.00561793183155, 
1.02137867838479, 1.00419895712406, 1.00806943530076, 1.0051794051368, 
0.999350635424913, 1.00973087623574, 1.00248828698632, 0.998570481084064, 
0.977479041013286, 1.01096951656124, 1.01351079135361, 1.00334999345842, 
1.00007280749211, 1.00462572177524, 0.993159840676654, 1.007365931375, 
1.00304600890457, 1.00670371626695, 1.01751675092252, 1.00988704448428, 
1.0203626352504, 1.017932042156, 1.01593562421343, 1.00829878987377, 
1.0140097704213, 1.0074163425617, 1.01295419489828, 1.0169905063817, 
1.0091803619272, 1.01899335754379, 1.00216329736003, 1.00873813814216, 
1.01089686979303, 1.0176902128014, 1.00613351701539, 1.0009981691645, 
1.0136469146848, 1.01141310603034, 1.00211555069364, 1.01766494128269, 
1.00738261826958, 1.00888569540471, 1.01136996437103, 1.00463942728414, 
1.00466784898992, 1.00968108462379, 1.00434610506521, 1.00841595586226, 
1.00304615189991, 1.00396154930567, 0.992392395499721, 0.996239699332347, 
1.00828766415394, 1.00498591313095, 0.999499549134277, 1.01872342445556, 
1.00678842240344, 1.01071920843834, 1.0119188821641, 1.00383424693643, 
1.00909612600239, 1.01112948233566, 1.00877853363443, 1.0114379665526, 
1.00778068215075, 1.00762517346382, 1.01081127260501, 1.00248883793245, 
1.00876670842244, 1.00906235482453, 1.00697565716213, 1.00922290030295, 
1.01075781602788, 1.00605419348162, 1.00796516966399, 1.01054089270218
), c_ratio_lag1 = c(1.01044698946802, 1.00112627043255, 1.00956669856575, 
1.01261408383412, 0.996003145177041, 1.00129520208562, 0.99962820498993, 
1.01488181722631, 1.00486289990812, 1.02011421903608, 1.01059294777674, 
1.01229352955197, 1.00805959142639, 1.01414889664505, 1.00700505295294, 
1.00943623572941, 1.01356599832316, 1.00833255198761, 1.01962662258791, 
1.01768923122687, 1.01847177760937, 1.0028545332765, 1.02230060773566, 
1.01102907149569, 1.01718247612036, 1.0281128019561, 1.01476254687286, 
1.00256251285869, 1.01141915081287, 1.0041661078677, 1.00576208863889, 
1.01367153452946, 1.00511999050122, 1.00611958848354, 1.02396492985109, 
1.01522741391098, 1.01874188217543, 1.00451081124232, 1.01108818020247, 
1.00645092025743, 1.00487541217674, 1.00799236140587, 1.00620479477444, 
1.00453007329697, 1.00876689818177, 0.997285249409703, 1.01919535868617, 
1.00919071730206, 1.00797274937055, 1.01659245530023, 1.01319827626499, 
1.01903670737095, 1.01541081813793, 1.02346671250822, 1.01825750409875, 
0.999549220766563, 1.00351966320795, 0.99701755092265, 0.991053263891484, 
1.00360053196551, 1.00429560051018, 0.985382868604157, 1.00838743909603, 
1.01644869260382, 1.01421243295163, 1.01075332180243, 1.01999389728661, 
1.00920047400176, 1.01052859560781, 1.01297484558686, 1.01178692459824, 
1.00542243256734, 1.00945559721015, 1.01503536104137, 1.00561793183155, 
1.02137867838479, 1.00419895712406, 1.00806943530076, 1.0051794051368, 
0.999350635424913, 1.00973087623574, 1.00248828698632, 0.998570481084064, 
0.977479041013286, 1.01096951656124, 1.01351079135361, 1.00334999345842, 
1.00007280749211, 1.00462572177524, 0.993159840676654, 1.007365931375, 
1.00304600890457, 1.00670371626695, 1.01751675092252, 1.00988704448428, 
1.0203626352504, 1.017932042156, 1.01593562421343, 1.00829878987377, 
1.0140097704213, 1.0074163425617, 1.01295419489828, 1.0169905063817, 
1.0091803619272, 1.01899335754379, 1.00216329736003, 1.00873813814216, 
1.01089686979303, 1.0176902128014, 1.00613351701539, 1.0009981691645, 
1.0136469146848, 1.01141310603034, 1.00211555069364, 1.01766494128269, 
1.00738261826958, 1.00888569540471, 1.01136996437103, 1.00463942728414, 
1.00466784898992, 1.00968108462379, 1.00434610506521, 1.00841595586226, 
1.00304615189991, 1.00396154930567, 0.992392395499721, 0.996239699332347, 
1.00828766415394, 1.00498591313095, 0.999499549134277, 1.01872342445556, 
1.00678842240344, 1.01071920843834, 1.0119188821641, 1.00383424693643, 
1.00909612600239, 1.01112948233566, 1.00877853363443, 1.0114379665526, 
1.00778068215075, 1.00762517346382, 1.01081127260501, 1.00248883793245, 
1.00876670842244, 1.00906235482453, 1.00697565716213, 1.00922290030295, 
1.01075781602788, 1.00605419348162, 1.00796516966399), c_ratio_lag2 = c(1.01544386843979, 
1.01044698946802, 1.00112627043255, 1.00956669856575, 1.01261408383412, 
0.996003145177041, 1.00129520208562, 0.99962820498993, 1.01488181722631, 
1.00486289990812, 1.02011421903608, 1.01059294777674, 1.01229352955197, 
1.00805959142639, 1.01414889664505, 1.00700505295294, 1.00943623572941, 
1.01356599832316, 1.00833255198761, 1.01962662258791, 1.01768923122687, 
1.01847177760937, 1.0028545332765, 1.02230060773566, 1.01102907149569, 
1.01718247612036, 1.0281128019561, 1.01476254687286, 1.00256251285869, 
1.01141915081287, 1.0041661078677, 1.00576208863889, 1.01367153452946, 
1.00511999050122, 1.00611958848354, 1.02396492985109, 1.01522741391098, 
1.01874188217543, 1.00451081124232, 1.01108818020247, 1.00645092025743, 
1.00487541217674, 1.00799236140587, 1.00620479477444, 1.00453007329697, 
1.00876689818177, 0.997285249409703, 1.01919535868617, 1.00919071730206, 
1.00797274937055, 1.01659245530023, 1.01319827626499, 1.01903670737095, 
1.01541081813793, 1.02346671250822, 1.01825750409875, 0.999549220766563, 
1.00351966320795, 0.99701755092265, 0.991053263891484, 1.00360053196551, 
1.00429560051018, 0.985382868604157, 1.00838743909603, 1.01644869260382, 
1.01421243295163, 1.01075332180243, 1.01999389728661, 1.00920047400176, 
1.01052859560781, 1.01297484558686, 1.01178692459824, 1.00542243256734, 
1.00945559721015, 1.01503536104137, 1.00561793183155, 1.02137867838479, 
1.00419895712406, 1.00806943530076, 1.0051794051368, 0.999350635424913, 
1.00973087623574, 1.00248828698632, 0.998570481084064, 0.977479041013286, 
1.01096951656124, 1.01351079135361, 1.00334999345842, 1.00007280749211, 
1.00462572177524, 0.993159840676654, 1.007365931375, 1.00304600890457, 
1.00670371626695, 1.01751675092252, 1.00988704448428, 1.0203626352504, 
1.017932042156, 1.01593562421343, 1.00829878987377, 1.0140097704213, 
1.0074163425617, 1.01295419489828, 1.0169905063817, 1.0091803619272, 
1.01899335754379, 1.00216329736003, 1.00873813814216, 1.01089686979303, 
1.0176902128014, 1.00613351701539, 1.0009981691645, 1.0136469146848, 
1.01141310603034, 1.00211555069364, 1.01766494128269, 1.00738261826958, 
1.00888569540471, 1.01136996437103, 1.00463942728414, 1.00466784898992, 
1.00968108462379, 1.00434610506521, 1.00841595586226, 1.00304615189991, 
1.00396154930567, 0.992392395499721, 0.996239699332347, 1.00828766415394, 
1.00498591313095, 0.999499549134277, 1.01872342445556, 1.00678842240344, 
1.01071920843834, 1.0119188821641, 1.00383424693643, 1.00909612600239, 
1.01112948233566, 1.00877853363443, 1.0114379665526, 1.00778068215075, 
1.00762517346382, 1.01081127260501, 1.00248883793245, 1.00876670842244, 
1.00906235482453, 1.00697565716213, 1.00922290030295, 1.01075781602788, 
1.00605419348162)), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```